# Bootstrap 3, changing collapsed stack order

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm working on a project using Bootstrap 3. I have my main content to the left, and a sidebar containing a menu on the right. When the columns are collapsed (col-md), I need the menu to display above the main content, but can't seem to achieve what I want with the push and pull classes.

My markup is simply:

```
<main class="col-md-8"></main>
<aside class="col-md-4"></aside>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to do this..

```
<aside class="col-md-4 col-md-push-8"></aside>
<main class="col-md-8 col-md-pull-4"></main>
```

Demo: http://www.bootply.com/119451

Comment: Hadn't even considered swapping them. Doh! Thanks.